# How can I export a phylogenetic tree I edited in R?

Tags: r, package, phylogeny

Alright so, I had a phylogenetic tree which I had to prune. I used the drop.tip command to remove the tips and I also changed the tip labels by making a data frame of the new names and importing it into the tip labels of the tree. The problem is when I tried to export it using the command write.beast but I get the following error message:

Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :
‘phylo’ is not a slot in class “phylo”

I needed to get a new file containing the new tree with less branches and with the new labels but im not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What's the class of your tree?

```
class(tree)
```

If the class is `phylo` `write.tree(tree)` is the right function. In that case the tip labels should be a vector.
If the class is `treedata` `write.beast` should work.

Keep in mind that support values can change (can get higher) if you prune away taxa and should be re-computed!